# How to achieve late binding in c# for Microsoft.office.interop.word?

Tags: c#

I want to achieve late binding for the following lines of code which are using early binding. How can I achieve it in C#?

When I removed Microsoft.office.interop.word reference, I am getting some errors, which are mentioned in the comments in following code.
Folloowing is the code I am using to convert a word document to pdf.

```
    Type wordType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");

        dynamic Word = Activator.CreateInstance(wordType);


        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\folder");
        FileInfo wordFile = new FileInfo(fileName);

        Word.Visible = false;
        Word.ScreenUpdating = false;

        Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;


        var doc = Word.Documents.Open(ref filename);
        doc.Activate();

        object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");

    /*Getting an error in WdSaveFormat */ 
        object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;



        doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName, ref fileFormat);



        /*Getting an error in WdSaveOptions */       
        object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;

    /*Getting an error in _Document*/ 
        ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges);
        doc = null;


        Word.Quit();


        MessageBox.Show("Successfully converted");
```

Comment: Can you give us real piece of your code and say where in said code you want to achieve that? I numbered list doesn't help much.

Comment: Just remove the casts.  The "Word" and "doc" variables must of course by of type *dynamic*.  You'll have to use integers instead of enums, pretty painful.  Not that much point in punishing yourself like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made the following changes, Its working fine now.

```
    Type wordType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");

    dynamic Word = Activator.CreateInstance(wordType);


    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\folder");
    FileInfo wordFile = new FileInfo(fileName);

    Word.Visible = false;
    Word.ScreenUpdating = false;

    Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

    var doc = Word.Documents.Open(ref filename);
    doc.Activate();

    object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");

/*in the WdSaveFormat enum, 17 is the value for pdf format*/ 
    object fileFormat = 17;


    doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName, ref fileFormat);

 /in the   WdSaveOptions enum, 0 is for Do not save pending changes.*/
    object saveChanges = 0;

    doc.Close(ref saveChanges);
    doc = null;

    Word.Quit();

    MessageBox.Show("Successfully converted");
```

Comment: not only it works but also the code is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, late binding was possible (and still is!) with reflection:

```
object word = ...;

object[] args = new object [] { oMissing, oMissing, oMissing };
word.GetType().InvokeMember( "Quit", 
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null, word, args );
```

With the introduction of dynamics in C#4, late binding is just a matter of switching to the dynamic binder:

```
dynamic word = ...;

word.Quit();
```

It is really as simple as that, you don't even have to pass these optional parameters to the `Quit` method. The only drawback is that there is no intellisense on the dynamically typed code.

More on that here in the Dino's article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714583.aspx

Comment: Thank you wiktor for your reply. Your reply along with your link helped me to undertand com objects better. I have modified my question. Kindly have a look.