# How to use enums with dynamic and word

Tags: c#, dynamic, enums, ms-word

In this function I load a template using Word and replace certain words with other words. That's not important. How do I change the function to use `dynamic`? In particular, how do I use the Enums (such as WdReplace.wdReplaceOne) without having a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

```
public static void CreateSheetByReplacement(String student, List<String> words)
{
    Application WordApp = new Application();
    WordApp.Documents.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\SpellingsReplace.dot");
    WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText: "studentname", Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne, Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue, ReplaceWith: student);
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        String word = (i < words.Count ? words[i] : "");
        WordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText: "[word" + (i + 1) + "]", Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne, Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue, ReplaceWith: word);
    }
    WordApp.Visible = true;
    WordApp = null;
}
```

I just need one example of how to use the enums.

Comment: If it's not important, don't include it in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "without having a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"? You already have to reference it due to `Application` and other classes from interop assemblies.

Comment: I won't have a reference when I use late binding with the dynamic keyword.

Comment: So you mean that you will inject `Application` into your method(class) as a dynamic object? Do not consider me rude, but nonetheless why do you need it? Perhaps it would be better just to abstract Interop with some custom interface? It is just my opinion but I think that `dynamic` shall be used only when it is really required(like dynamic languages interop) or when it greatly improves some code aspect.

Comment: It's more curiosity. I don't know how to do it and having spent half an hour googling it am none the wiser. Also, I am getting an error with the assembly reference about wrong version.

Comment: @YohDeadfall  I read the question you say is a duplicate and it did not help. Perhaps I am just not understanding it.

Comment: Using late binding for Office interop assemblies was explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873825/how-to-achieve-late-binding-in-c-sharp-for-microsoft-office-interop-word).

Comment: I've read both of those. I am still none the wiser.

Comment: Then you probably read in Peter's comment that you will have to use integers instead enums (see the link). My comment was about using enums while you are referencing .Net assemblies. So I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way to easily use enums with such `dynamic` late binding other than by directly using respective Integer values, you can use some reflection and `ExpandoObject` to build dynamic lookup object:

```
public static class DynamicInterop
{
    public static DynamicInterop()
    {
        var enumsDict = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

        // Get all enum types from interop assembly
        var interopEnums = GetInteropAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type =>
                typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(type));

        // For all enum types create a member in the enums dynamic object
        foreach (var type in interopEnums)
        {
            var curEnum = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

            // Get Enum value name and values as KeyValuePairs
            var enumKeyValues = Enum
                .GetNames(type)
                .Zip(Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Object>(), 
                    (key, value) =>
                        new KeyValuePair<String, Object>(key, value));

            // Create members for every enum value name-value pair
            foreach (var keyValue in enumKeyValues)
            {
                curEnum.Add(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
            }

            enumsDict.Add(type.Name, curEnum);
        }

        DynamicInterop.Enums = enumsDict;
    }

    public static dynamic CreateWordApp()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static dynamic Enums
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

While such approach may not exactly suit your needs it will at least reduce the probability of passing wrong enum value.

**P.S.:** It is not tested, so there are may be few typos or other errors.

**P.S.1:** Still, with no Intellisense and other IDE and compiler assistance late binding to Interop with `dynamic` can easily become the most difficult part of the code to maintain.