# Insert text into an existing Word

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

I'm need to add text into an already opened Word document, using some equivalent of the GetObject(, "Word.Application") in VB. But I can't use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` because I want it to be compatible with all versions of Word.

**EDIT**
It should do the same as the following VB code:

```
    Dim word As Object
    Dim text As String

    word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    text = TextBox1.Text
    word.Selection.Font.Bold = True

    word.Selection.TypeText(text)

    word = Nothing
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Search for "later binding", e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23873825/1997232) is something. With `dynamic` it's pretty easy now.

Comment: Even if you can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` I'd seek to avoid it. For clarification - does your app need to be compatible with all versions of Word in the sense that users might have different versions installed, or compatible with documents from any version of Word? If you're working with .docx files then you can edit the file directly using OpenXML without automating Word at all. That way it wouldn't matter what version of Word they had installed - they wouldn't even need it at all.

Comment: @ScottHannen it should be compatible with all versions of Word. As an example, if I use `interop` for Office 2016 and in the next version they change anything the app would not work for that version, that's why I'm avoiding that.

Comment: @Sinatr I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @Sinatr How do I use dynamic to write to an existing document? VS won't let me run the program, it's complaining about the dynamic variable. Could you post some example code or point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Carles, there is a link in my first comment (you can also find it under "Linked" category on the right side under advertisements), did you check it? It has an accepted answer. If you get an error and not able to solve it - you can ask another question, make sure to add the attempted code, complete error message and explanation what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Sinatr yes I did check it, and also searched for `late binding` in google and I'm not able to figure this one out.